# "Вместо этого" и его обособление

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В голове родился вопрос, на который интернет не смог дать мне незамедлительного ответа: обособляется ли словосочетание "вместо этого" в предложениях?

Я предположил два варианта восприятия оного объединения слов. Я продемонстрирую их на примерах:
1) Я мог бы заняться чем-нибудь действительно важным(,) вместо этой бумажной волокиты.
2) Сегодня мне пришлось работать с бумагами. Я(,) вместо этого(,) мог бы заняться чем-нибудь действительно важным.

По моему мнению, в первом примере запятая интонационно неуместна. Касательно же второго варианта ответить затрудняюсь, поэтому прошу совета в текущей дилемме от более опытных любителей русской пунктуации.

P.S. При обнаружении различных ошибок в тексте также прошу не избегать критики.

Comment: Если в ответе есть полезная информация - можете поставить лайк - нажать на верхний серый треугольник. Если ответ решил проблему - поставить зелёную галочку (она может быть только у одного ответа). http://i.imgur.com/jnvr8HZ.png При этом отвечающие понимают, что не зря старались и что их ответ помог.

Comment: *P.S. При обнаружении различных ошибок в тексте также прошу не избегать критики*.
А вот этого не стоит просить. На ошибки вам еще могут указать, если кому-то невтерпеж будет. Но критика автора вопроса - да еще не по теме! - это уже злостный оффтоп.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что пишет Д. Э. Розенталь ([§ 21. Обособленные дополнения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=38)).

В зависимости от смысловой нагрузки, степени распространения оборота, близости к основной части предложения и т. д. могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) существительные с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями *кроме, **вместо**, помимо, сверх, за исключением, наряду с* и др. (условно называемые дополнениями) с ограничительным или расширительным значением, т. е. в к л ю ч е н и я, и с к л ю ч е н и я, з а м е щ е н и я:
*Тут, кроме небольшого столика с зеркалом, табурета и тряпья, развешанного по углам, не было никакой другой мебели и, **вместо лампы,** горел яркий веерообразный огонёк* (Чехов).

Обособление или необособление таких оборотов **ф а к у л ь т а т и в н о.**
Сравните: ***Вместо голых утёсов,*** я увидел около себя зелёные горы и плодоносные деревья (П.); *У заставы **вместо часового** стояла развалившаяся будка* (П.).

Считаю, что в Ваших предложениях указанные запятые не нужны — даже как авторские.
Для подчеркивания, думаю, возможно написать так.

Я мог бы заняться чем-нибудь действительно важным — вместо этой бумажной волокиты.

Сегодня мне пришлось работать с бумагами. А ведь вместо этого мог бы заняться чем-нибудь действительно важным!

В предложениях, имеющихся в [НКРЯ](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1992&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE&endyear=2012&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&p=7), "вместо этого" в подавляющем большинстве случаев не обособляется. Вот в этом примере (он первый по ссылке из комментария) запятую после "этого" считаю необоснованной.
*Стесняются просить о повышении зарплаты, вместо этого, прилюдно жалуясь на свои финансовые затруднения.*

P. S. Изменения внесены после комментария участника *slava1947*.

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: В предложениях, имеющихся в НКРЯ, "вместо этого" не обособляется._ === ??????????? См. примеры: http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=acomma&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min1=1&max1=1&lex2=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=bcomma&m2=

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылку — я внесла изменения в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не требуются. *Вместо этого* - **не уточнение** и не вводное словосочетание.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_287

В первом примере ещё как-то можно поставить запятую, если рассматривать "вместо этой..." как уточнение:
*Я мог бы заняться чем-нибудь действительно важным, (а именно) вместо этой бумажной волокиты.* || То есть заняться чем-то важным **в общем**. А оборот несёт дополнительную информацию, чем человек занимается в данный период. Тогда и пауза должна присутствовать при чтении. Но это авторская пунктуация, которая раскрывает особый смысл, заложенный автором.

Во втором примере запятые не подходят. Уточнять там нечего, так как почти начало предложения. Просто не совсем естественный порядок слов (лучше в самое начало поставить), и создаётся иллюзия, что нужны запятые. "Вместо этого" является важным элементом смысла (чему способствует позиция в начале предложения и после подлежащего) - его не нужно отделять запятыми.

Обособление часто происходит при больших оборотах:
*Быстрыми шагами прошёл я длинную «площадь» кустов, взобрался на холм и, **вместо ожиданной знакомой равнины с дубовым леском направо и низенькой белой церковью в отдалении**, увидел совершенно другие, мне неизвестные места.*

В случаях обособления подобные обороты имеют характер **смыслового дополнения**. То есть при их изъятии "центральный" смысл особо не теряется:
*Многие из бойцов, **помимо своей винтовки**, были вооружены трофейными автоматами.* || Дополнительная информация, что у бойцов была ещё и винтовка. Оборот не является центральным элементом смысла.

Для выяснения пунктуации в подобных оборотах автору стоит исходить из наличия **интонационных пауз** при чтении. А они в данных двух примерах отсутствуют.

Answer (score 0):

> обособляется ли словосочетание "вместо этого" в предложениях?

Нет. А на каком основании-то ему обособляться?

> В голове родился вопрос, на который интернет не смог дать мне незамедлительного ответа:

Интересно, а как вы его спрашивали? Найдите в нацкорпусе хоть один случай обособления - тогда хоть смысл вопроса понятен будет.

> Я предположил два варианта восприятия оного объединения слов

Я бы посоветовал вам поменьше предполагать - и больше ориентироваться на правила.

> 1) Я мог бы заняться чем-нибудь действительно важным (,) вместо этой
>   бумажной волокиты.

Здесь запятая никакими разумными доводами не мотивируется.

> 2) Сегодня мне пришлось работать с бумагами. Я (,) вместо этого (,)
>   мог бы заняться чем-нибудь действительно важным.

Здесь автор еще мог бы сослаться на авторское восприятие, то есть на интонационную пунктуацию, но очень сомнительно, что его доводы сочтут убедительным.